# Data archiving from DynamoDB to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to archive data from a `DynamoDB to s3 using Kinesis Data Stream and firehose.`

Both Old Image and New Image of the item are getting saved in S3. Which creates duplicate data in s3.

Can someone help to guide in saving either new Image or old image within S3?

Comment: is the name of iold and new mages same? if yes you can enable s3 versioning which will create versions of a same object whenever the object gets updated.

Comment: Its  both the new and the old images of the item from dynamo

Comment: What's the purpose of the data in S3? I.e., do you only need the latest data as a backup, or do you need an event log of every action?

Comment: Archieve the data older than 3 months to be save to s3

Comment: `Its both the new and the old images of the item from dynamo ` what does this mean,is the same of images same?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use data transformation on Kinesis before sending data to S3.

In basic terms, you program Kinesis to invoke a Lambda function, which will receive your DynamoDB stream entries, extract only NewImage or OldImage, and return it back to Kinesis. Only then Kinesis will deliver to S3.

Here's a [tutorial by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html).